# How to create Chat application using Servlets & JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I want to create chat application using Servlets & JSP. May I know how can I create chat application as I have never created before?

How much knowledge I need to have to create chat application?

Is there any need of networking API to create chat application?

What's the design pattern I need to follow to create that application?

Is there any need of database?

Comment: It is a school project? This is namely a typical school project. You should tag accordingly with `homework`. Copypasting other's code may namely give you less points or even completely fail.

Answer (score 5):

Its already done here [Chat Servlet](http://coldjava.hypermart.net/servlets/chat.htm)